# video problem after upgrade 10.04 to 11.04

Tags: fglrx

after upgrading to 11.04, screen shows 'razor-type' diagonal lines, overlapping text, missing lines etc. which go away, when move (refresh) the page up or down.
kernel version 2.6.38-11-generic. 
graphics card: mobility Radeon 9600 M10

following [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI?action=show&redirect=RestrictedDrivers/ATI) instructions, I d/l ATI fglrx drivers 9-3-x86.x86_64, but never install completely. I get the  msg      **-iscurrentdistro**, then I try **--listpgk** and then **--buildpkg Ubuntu/9.04** supposingly to build drivers for earlier version. But no matter what I do, the drivers never install completely: Get the msg

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   fglrx-kernel-source
>   libamdxvbal
>   xorg-driver-fglrx
>   xorg-driver-fglrx
>   fglrx-amdcccle

Read somewhere that this could be broken packages, and with synaptics tried to fix first 2 files that were broken, but then the error is:

> cannot install fglrx-kernel-source....

tried to go back to the open source drivers as  here[remove fglrx and install ati from scratch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch) the drivers install, but the 'razor' effects, overlapping lines etc, come back.

By the way, tried system>administation>additional drivers, found fglrx drivers, but pressing 'activate' doesn't do anything.

Problem remains with Unity or Classic "view"
Is the kernel/card too old for both the open source AND the fglrx drivers?
Or maybe the buffer on  the graphics card is messed up?   t
Thank you all
stanlex

Answer (score 1):

The Radeon 9600 is no longer supported by ATI after 10.04, if you can't use the open-source drivers then your best bet is to not upgrade.

Comment: ok clear better go back to 10.04 then thanks stanlex